# Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator with $Ker(T) = \{ 0 \}$. Show that if $V$ is finite dimensional, then $T$ is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

As a follow up question:

Does the same hold if $V$ has infinite dimension? Prove or give a counter-example.

I know that for finite dimensional spaces, surjectivity implies injectivity and vice-versa (although I do not know why). I also know there is a theorem that states that if $T$ is injective, then $ker(T) = \{ 0 \}$.

Help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for the finite dimensional case, you have already writen everything you need. $\operatorname{ker}(T) = \{0\}$ implies $T$ is injective, which is equivalent to $T$ being surjective.

As for the infinite dimensional case, consider a vector space $V$ with a countable infitinte base $B=\{b_i| i \in \mathbb N\}$. Choose $T$ so that $T(b_i) = b_{i+1}$. $T$ is injective, but not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

If is finite dimensional then $\dim V= \dim (\ker (T))+ \dim((T(V)))$, where $T(V)$ is the Image. So if $\ker T=\{0\}$, the dimension is zero, and then $\dim V=\dim((T(V)))$ which shows that is surjective.

For the infinite dimensional case, take for example: if $e_i$ is the infinite sequence with $1$ in $i$-th position and zero everywhere else, for example $e_1= (1,0,...)$, and define the shift operator, i.e., $e_i \mapsto e_{i+1}$ so is injective but not surjective.